# iPhone - Problem with “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, iad

i've a problem. Serius problem. -.-''    I've an app ViewBased, with MainView and FlipsideView. When i tap on the info button the FlipsideView will appears. But when i tap Done button, sometimes, the app terminates with “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” and i don't know what i have to do!!! In the Flipside view i've also an iAd banner, managed by this code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

        [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:12]];

        adView=[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 460.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier=ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        [self.view addSubview:adView];
        self.adView.delegate=self;
        self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

        UIDevice *theDevice=[UIDevice currentDevice];
        NSString *iOS;
        iOS=theDevice.systemVersion;
        float iOS2 = [iOS floatValue];

        if (iOS2>=4.0) {
            self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
        }

        [super viewDidLoad];

    }

    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        if(!self.bannerIsVisible) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
            banner.frame=CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50.0f);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            self.bannerIsVisible=YES;
        }
    }
```

There's something wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `[super viewDidLoad];` twice?

Comment: i don't know O.O i've mistaken :P   i've deleted the first [super viewDidLoad]; and all works great :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `[super viewDidLoad];` twice.

Answer (score 0):

set the environment variable NSZombieEnabled = YES and the run the code again. Then watch your crash logs. You are trying to access an already deallocated instance.